# MacOS man pages out of date

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, xcode, development

I’ve caught a few POSIX options unavailable on a MacOS man page (but are supported — they compile). Is there a way to submit a patch to the kernel developers?

Comment: Related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/379099/are-my-macos-man-pages-outdated?rq=1

Comment: Also, did you check whether the developer documentation on https://developer.apple.com/ is more up-to-date?

Comment: I did @nohillside . Same as my machine’s man pages

Comment: It's probably not very high on the to-do list to keep these man pages up to date, hardly any macOS developer works on system call/POSIX level.

Comment: The Darwin kernel (now XNU) *is* open source.  Maybe you could [submit a pull request documenting specific issues you found](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/xnu/pulls) on their [GitHub page](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/xnu)?

Answer (score 1):

Just [file them a bug report](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/) using the [Feedback Assistant](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/) and hope they’ll see it.